Dynamically populate table values for migrating data
I have a database that was split due to collation issues because of a server migration.

I have the merge1 database which is the older database free of corrupted data however it lacks newer entries.

I have the merge2 database which has all of the entries (old and new) however many of the older entries are corrupted (the newer entries are fine).

Both databases are on the exact same MariaDB database server am I'm already aware of how to do things like database selectors (merge1.table3).

I'm using the MariaDB root user that is not exposed to the public as I consider this purely internal maintenance only.

There are absolutely zero database structural differences between the two databases and there will be no structural changes until no sooner than this database merger has been completed with none currently planned any way.


So far I've done a good chunk of work with the information_schema.COLUMNS database and table (TABLE_NAME and COLUMN_NAME) So I have a list of all the rows for every table:
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='merge1';

Now that the "big picture" is established I'm trying to determine if and how to make the job easier by dynamically constructing the queries as there are a lot of tables and some have a lot of columns. So let's table table3 has x number of columns (two columns, dozens, etc. I already know that the merge1 table has 200 base entries so I only need to INSERT 201+ (a static example to keep things simple).
So here is my rough non-working example:
INSERT INTO merge1.table3 
(
 SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
 FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='merge1'
)
VALUES 
(
 SELECT * FROM merge2.table3 information_schema WHERE id>200
);

The problem seems rooted in the values being inserted as MariaDB seems to be content with the sub-SELECT providing the column names. Perhaps I'm not dynamically constructing the second half of the query?
How do I fix/improve the query to provide the matching column names without being forced to statically define them?

It seems to me that you need insert ignore into tables.merge1 select * from merge2.tables.  Have you tried that ?

if you have a primary key on your tables you can use insert ignore https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-ignore/

Okay, I will try those the suggestions out and report back, thank you,

When getting info from information_schema (such as COLUMN NAME), you must generate an SQL string that you then execute.  This can be done in a Stored procedure.

@RickJames Is there an article or post where you could further elaborate? Also it seems that you're referring to a read event instead of write. Without rehashing two weeks worth of work - everything I've done seems to be working fine though I'm always open to the possibility that I missed something somewhere.

Thanks to Ergest Basha and nbk for their helpful comments I was able to copy newer records to an older database without complications or problems by using:
INSERT IGNORE INTO $db1.$table SELECT * FROM $db2.$table;

It really doesn't get any simpler than that.
